# Android/IOS Native SDK integration in expo application

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, sdk

I am creating react native expo application for ,android, ios and web.
My requirement is to integrated native IOS or native Android sdk into my expo application.
I have external native Android and ios SDK code that i want to integrate in my expo application based on platform
In React native we have android and ios folder , where we can make changes for this requirement, but I could not see proper explantion for expo application.

I went through expo documentation and youtube videos,but I am getting confused for , it is telling about native modules, not sdk.

Am I missing something, What topic shoul i cover for native sdk requirement in expo application.
Or Any resources that have explained about this?

Comment: anyone from react native world?

Comment: anyone, any input?

Comment: Hi, i'm facing the same issue. Could you find any solution? I don't understand how to properly add a native Android/iOS SDK into my Expo project. Besides, it's really hard to find something about on the iInternet